# The best overload method match .... c# databounditem

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

i am trying to pass selected row from datagridview1 (form1) to datagridview1(form 4) and this is my list of codes..but i am getting error. As my programming skill isn't very well, do explain in details if you can clarify the problem... thanks.

```
        if (tableListBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            List<string> sendingList = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                sendingList.Add(dr.DataBoundItem);// The best overload method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid argument

            }
            Form4 form4 = new Form4(sendingList);
            form4.Show();

        }
```

Comment: Hint: You're trying to store something in a list of `string` that isn't a `string`. Perhaps try casting the `DataBoundItem` to a `string`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead and how do i do that? sorry i am quite new to programming... do you have any website that maybe i could refer to? thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either change the type of your list to objects, or convert your object to a string (using 'dr.DataBoundItem as string'). SendingList is a list of strings, so you can't add an object to it without converting it first.

To convert the object to a string (assuming it is a string that was converted to an object):

```
sendingList.Add(dr.DataBoundItem as string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because your type doesn't match.  If you look at [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx) you can see that it is defined as follows.

```
public Object DataBoundItem { get; }
```

This means that the return type is `Object`.  The error is because the `List<T>.Add()` method expects the parameter to be of type T in your case `List<string>.Add(string)`.  The list should be the of the type that DataBoundItem can be cast into.  Looking at the example in the help page...

```
void invoiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        Customer cust = row.DataBoundItem as Customer;
        if (cust != null)
        {
            cust.SendInvoice();
        }
    }
}
```

The DataBoundItem is cast as a Customer object.  And if you wanted to capture them into a list it would be a `List<Customer>`.  You could also use a `List<object>` however it is preferred that objects are [strongly typed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173104.aspx).